# How do I have any privacy on my mini iPad?

Tags: ipad, security, hacking

So my sister & her boyfriend are all into this hacking and spying and invading people's privacy and doing malicious things to the with what they gather. They have been doing it to me and trying to break up my long term relationship and have hacked into 2 of my mini iPads, an iPhone 4, quite a few windows phones as well as approx 5 androids and ruined all of them. I have a brand new mini iPad and android phone but don't want them in them messing them up too.

How do I keep them from hacking or viewing my iPad when I unbox it?

I know they use [metasploit](https://www.metasploit.com) and [nmaps](http://www.nmaps.net) to do their dirty work, although don't know what these things are or do. Also, we live together so we use same wifi connection. This has truly been a nightmare that has caused and they are causing detrimentally negative results. It has taken my life as I knew it and what I made of it and I trying to stop them from it, but they refuse.

So I'm hoping if I can somehow block all syncing with other devices, mirror images, keep them out of my iCloud account and maybe some security or something I can keep them out, but I know nothing about this stuff and need help.

Apple could only tell me to 2 step my iCloud account, which did no good considering they have access to my phone, all emails and my iPad. Thanks!

Comment: They only have access if you don't lock them - if you 2 step iCloud and you have a password on your phone how do they get access

Comment: Whilst we can be sympathetic to your plight, there is really not much actual information in your question that we have to go on. As @Mark says, if it's locked & using 2-step authentication, then they would have to know your passcode or iCloud log/pass to have any access.

Comment: There's buttons you can push on cell phones (I assume iPads as well) in case you lock yourself out of your phone or have issues with it and get locked out that bypass a home screen code. Plus they use these tricks from metssploit and IMAP and he told me he has a password cracker program that he can get any password to any email he says. I am not a computer literate person so I don't know anything except what icn

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry about what sounds like a very unfortunate situation. I would enable strong passcodes and use two step authentication. On your iPad, go to preferences and set up a strong alpha-numerical password (not a 4 digit pin) for your device in general. Since it is a new device, Touch ID should make that a minimal burden.

Next, go to https://appleid.apple.com, and **enable two step authentication on your Apple ID**.

Finally, as I'm sure would be obvious, don't share your passwords with them, and you could always enable Airplane mode every night to prevent them from having access to it over night via the wifi.

Regarding your android, I would hope there are similar steps but don't know.

Answer (score 2):

First, physically gather all your iOS devices and Macs and make sure no one else will be able to touch them until you have secured all of them.

1. Set up a passcode on all of them.  (At this stage you can just use something simple, like 1111.)
2. Turn off the simple passcode option.
3. Set up new passcodes that are

   - non-trivial,
   - not easily guessable
   - has both letters and numbers
   - has at least 6 characters
4. Ideally, use a different passcode on each device.
5. Set them all to *require passcode immediately*.
6. Where available, set up TouchID and fill up all the finger slots.
7. Turn off [location sharing with friends and family](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201087).

Now [login to your iCloud](https://appleid.apple.com) account.

1. Edit the number of trusted devices down to one or two, ideally only those that have TouchID.
2. Change your password.  Pick something that is non-trivial and not easily guessable.  (You will have to approve the password change on a trusted device.)

Don't share your iCloud password or your passcode with *anybody*.  Do not write down the password or passcodes *anywhere* (unless you can encrypt them).  Avoid typing in the passcodes as much as possible, and especially in public, always use touch to unlock your device.

If you are using a Mac as a hub, change all admin accounts' passwords, and *your* account password, set it up to boot to a login screen, require it to ask for the password whenever the display goes to sleep, and turn off all Sharing options that you don't explicitly use.

Then change all your account passwords everywhere (gmail, yahoo, Facebook, bank account, whatever).

Avoid using the same password at different places.  There are many guides on best practices in choosing unique passwords.  Use contractions of word sequences that make sense to you, salt them, and use password storage methods like keychain, iCloud keychain, 1Password, Lastpass, etc.

No idea about android devices, sorry.